# JQuery Onclick Function

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I am using the following code,

```
function slideonlyone(thechosenone,selectedHeader) {
    $("#navigation li a").each(function(){
        $(this).removeClass("active");
        $(selectedHeader).addClass("active");
    });     
    $('div[name|="newboxes2"]').each(function (index) {         
        if ($(this).attr("id") == thechosenone) {               
            $(this).slideDown(600);
            $(this).removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");
        }
        else {
            $(this).slideUp(600);
        }
    });
}
function goToByScroll(id){
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top},'slow');
    return false;       
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a.close-btn').click(function () {        
        $('div[name|="newboxes2"]').slideUp(600);
    });     
});
```

Everything is working fine. Except the one.
My below function is working fine but on second click, i want it to work as the navigation link is click.

```
function goToByScroll(id){
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top},'slow');
    return false;       
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Which one is 'the one'? I don't think you mean Neo?

Comment: You don't have any logic in place to make it function differently on subsequent clicks, if that's what you want. You mention "the one" (nice one, hopla. ;-) ) ... did you try to use jQuery's `.one()` at some point? Because it's not in your code sample..

Comment: I have added the one which is not working....

Answer (score 0):

jQuery permite hacer un trigger de los eventos .trigger( event ) y lo coloca en el link apuntando al evento

On jquery you can trigger event with .trigger( event ), you call this on the link event to call the event that you want to execute

Comment: hello cesarlarsson here is the link for that .... http://www.mannatstudio.com/stackoverflow/index.html, please help me as soon as possible. Thanks.